# Measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

[image]I have this lemma that shows measurability of functions.I don't understand the unions and intersection parts,I understand that if (a) holds then (b) holds but I don't see how we can write (c) and (d) as unions and intersects.

Comment: It is unclear what you don't understand. Please be more precise, and explain how you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Okay,so we have $A_\alpha$ belongs to $\sigma-algebra$ defined on X then it's complement belongs to the $\sigma-algebra$ on X by definition. So $(a)\to (b)$ is satisfied,now from $(b) \to (c)$ if $x_0 \in A_\alpha$ then $x_0 \in C_\alpha$.$A_{\alpha-\frac{1}{n}} ={x\in:f(x)\le\alpha-\frac{1}{n}}$.now we know $\frac{1}{n}>0$ so $A_{\alpha-\frac{1}{n}}\subset C_\alpha$ I don't know how to proceed from here and also don't understand why $C_\alpha$ is now the intersection of  $A_{\alpha-\frac{1}{n}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see why $C_\alpha = \cap_{n=1}^\infty A_{\alpha - \frac1n}$, let us first choose an element $x \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty A_{\alpha - \frac1n}$. Suppose $x \notin C_\alpha$, then it follows that $f(x) < \alpha$ by definition. Therefore, $\alpha-f(x)>0$ and we can therefore find a natural number $N$ such that $\alpha - f(x) > \frac1N$. However, then $f(x)< \alpha - \frac1N$, thus $f(x) \notin A_{\alpha - \frac1N} \subset \cap_{n=1}^\infty A_{\alpha - \frac1n}$. This is a contradiction, and therefore $x \in C_\alpha$. Since this argument does not depend on the choice of $x$, $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_{\alpha - \frac1n} \subset C_\alpha$.

For the other inclusion, suppose $x \in C_\alpha$. We need to show that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \in A_{\alpha - \frac{1}{n}}$. This follows immediately from the fact that $f(x) \geq \alpha > \alpha - \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $C_\alpha = \cap_{n=1}^\infty A_{\alpha - \frac1n}.$

The argument for the unions is similar.